# WHY does it initialize this Knockout.js component in random order?

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, knockout-components, knockout-templating

I am ***beyond*** confused...

I am creating a list using Knockout.js components, templates, and custom elements. For some reason, the steps I create in my `Viewmodel` are being initialized in random order within the custom element definition! And it is completely randomized so that it is different **each** time!

To help better illustrate this, it is best to look at the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uu4hzc41/8/). I put `alert("break")` after each step initialization. ***Load it once, and then click "run" again to see the demo properly.*** Look in the output window and you can see that other than step 1 being written first, the steps always appear *randomly* (though they maintain their order in the end).

https://jsfiddle.net/uu4hzc41/8/

I need to have these in the correct order because I will add certain attributes from my model into an array. When they are random I can't access the array elements properly.

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <sidebar-step params="vm: sidebarStepModel0"></sidebar-step>
    <sidebar-step params="vm: sidebarStepModel1"></sidebar-step>
    <sidebar-step params="vm: sidebarStepModel2"></sidebar-step>
    <sidebar-step params="vm: sidebarStepModel3"></sidebar-step>
    <sidebar-step params="vm: sidebarStepModel4"></sidebar-step>
</ul>
```

JS/Knockout:

```
//custom element <sidebar-step>
ko.components.register("sidebar-step", {
    viewModel: function (params) {
        this.vm = params.vm;
        alert("break");
    },

    template: "<li data-bind='text: vm.message'>vm.onChangeElement</li>"
});

// model
var SidebarStepModel = function () {
    this.message = ko.observable("step description");

};

// viewmodel
var OrderGuideViewModel = function () {

    this.sidebarStepModel0 = new SidebarStepModel();
    this.sidebarStepModel0.message("step 1");


    this.sidebarStepModel1 = new SidebarStepModel();
    this.sidebarStepModel1.message("step 2");


    this.sidebarStepModel2 = new SidebarStepModel();
    this.sidebarStepModel2.message("step 3");


    this.sidebarStepModel3 = new SidebarStepModel();
    this.sidebarStepModel3.message("step 4");


    this.sidebarStepModel4 = new SidebarStepModel();
    this.sidebarStepModel4.message("step 5");


};

ko.applyBindings(new OrderGuideViewModel());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default knockout components load asynchronously.  In [version 3.3](http://www.knockmeout.net/2015/02/knockout-3-3-released.html) an option was added to allow the component to load synchronously.

Add synchronous:true when registering to get the behavior you want.

Example:

```
ko.components.register("sidebar-step", {
    viewModel: function (params) {
        this.vm = params.vm;
        alert("break");
    },

    template: "<li data-bind='text: vm.message'>vm.onChangeElement</li>",
    synchronous: true
});
```

Comment: Wow, such a simple answer to what I thought was a complicated issue! Async operations didn't even cross my mind! Here is the updated fiddle for anyone who cares - you can see the steps load in correct order now! - https://jsfiddle.net/uu4hzc41/9/